# How to handle infeasible points in FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, warning-messages

I am calling

```
FindRoot[f[x,y],{{x,xInit,xMin,xMax},{y,yInit,yMin,yMax}}]
```

where for some points `{x,y}`, `f[x,y]` is undefined. I now wonder which value `f[x,y]` should return at `{x,y}` in order for `FindRoot` to neglect these points, and to continue searching. Should `f` maybe return `Null` or `Indeterminate` at the critical `{x,y}`?

Note, that so far I have not added any domain restrictions on `f`. I also do not know whether adding domain restrictions would be a possibility?

To give some more background: `f[x,y]` is a composite function of other functions of `x` and `y`. For some points `{x,y}`, bounds for integrals inside these functions become complex, which is nonsensical.

Currently, I throw an error as far as possible down the tree of interdependent functions - call the function where I do this `l`. Points `{x,y}` are infeasible if `g[x,y]<h[x,y]`.

```
l[x_,y_]:=Module[{...},If[g[x,y]<h[x,y],Throw["Error"],Null],...]
```

However, I am not catching this error properly and `FindRoot` terminates.